# How to load a file from the installation folder of a C++ WinUI 3.0 application

Tags: c++-winrt, winui-3

I'm porting a UWP app over to Win32 with WinUI 3.0. In that UWP app I'm loading file resources from the app installation folder as follows:

```cpp
std::vector<char> MyStorage::ReadFileFromStorageFolder(const std::wstring& relativePath)
{
  path filePath = path{ Package::Current().InstalledLocation().Path().data() } / path{ relativePath };

  std::ifstream           inputFileStream(filePath, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
  std::ifstream::pos_type pos = inputFileStream.tellg();

  std::vector<char> result(pos);

  inputFileStream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
  inputFileStream.read(&result[0], pos);

  return result;
}
```

Unfortunately, the code `Package::Current().InstalledLocation()` causes the Win32 WinUI 3.0 app to hang. How would I do this so that it works in the Win32 WinUI 3.0 app?

Comment: Does  Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location do the job?

Comment: This looks like .NET functionality. The C++ equivalent of this is likely what I'm looking for (I clarified the title of the question). Any idea how to do this in C++?

Comment: The traditional way of referencing application-relative assets from a Win32 application is to query the location of the executing module. [`GetModuleFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew) can be used for that, then stripping the file name and appending the relative path of the asset in question. I'm sure there is a more modern way of doing this, but frankly, the whole packaged vs. unpackaged mess has left me scratching my head on more than one occasion.

Comment: I call Package.Current.InstalledLocation() in C# and it hangs there as well